Issue in Selenium WebDriver while deploying the same on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with C# with .NET8
We have developed web scraping tool to post data in application that will be opened in chrome browser. We are able to run smoothly on windows. While running the same on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, below is the case:
While running through VS Code in debug mode it's working fine.
When we publish it and deploy the same in systemd service then it's showing below exception:
Starting ChromeDriver 127.0.6533.99 (f31af5097d90ef5ae5bd7b8700199bc6189ba34d-refs/branch-heads/6533@{#1910}) on port 42457 
Only local connections are allowed. 
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. 
ChromeDriver was started successfully. 
[13:22:02 ERR] session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) 
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
(SessionNotCreated) System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. 
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) 
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
(SessionNotCreated) at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute) at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.ExecuteAsync(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary2 parameters) at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities capabilities) at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities) at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)

Please note, I am able to run with headless options but we required to user interaction before proceeding for operation due to security reasons.
